# Defining URL path in $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm newbie to AngularJS, and wanted to replicate/configure the following two URIs/paths:

```
reports/search/findBySomeText?keyword=hello&filter=list
reports?filter=list
```

in `$resource`. So far I've come up with below, but not sure if it's correct:

```
var Report = $resource('reports/:search/:findBySomeText/:id', {
            id: '@id'
        }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false,
                search : '@search',
                findBySomeText: '@findBySomeText',
                params: {
                   filter: 'list',
                   keyword: '@keyword'
                }
            },
            generate: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    generate: true
                }
            }
        });
```

So can someone here correct/or guide me to how I would achieve this behavior please!

`NOTE` - if possible, I would like to keep the base url as `api/reports/:id` and add the other uri behaviors to vary!
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you.

```
$resource('api/reports/findBySomeText?:keyword&:filter', { keyword: '@keyword', filter: '@filter' }).get({ keyword: 'hello', filter: 'list' });

$resource('api/reports/?:filter', { filter: '@filter' }).post({ filter: 'list' });
```

If Filter -> List is actually a list of filters, you can concatenate them in your url like so 'filter=item1&filter=item2&filter=item3' to get a filter list like ["item1","item2","item3"]

Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for. I had to make a couple of guesses.

Comment: Is it possible to have a single `resource` object instead of two? Also is it possible to stick from here onward into `params : {...}` list?